# Normalized Image Histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization

I have an RGB image `m` in MATLAB

[image: IMG]

I normalized it using the formula

```
im = mean(m,3);
im = (im-min(im(:))) / (max(im(:))-min(im(:)));
```

I read that the normalized module stretches the image pixel values to cover the entire pixel value range (0-1) but I still have some steps between 0 and 1 in the histogram of my normalized image.

[image]

Can anyone help me out here by explaining the reason of these grey values.

Thank You

Comment: To clarify: You would like to have a binary image (only 0  and 1)?

Comment: When I convert my Image to binary I have just 0 and 1 values in my histogram. I want to know why do I have 4 steps in my Normalized RGB Histogram if it stretches the values to zero or 1.

Comment: Probably because you haven't binarised it properly. Post some sample data and how you binarised it and I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: Where is your RGB separation / slicing? Normalising per colour-plane gives 3-histograms or a complex one, using some RGB-based scalar ( for example a Lightness-scalar, or a Saturation-scalar ) according to which to process the normalisation calculus.

Comment: I will add the image and the normalizing step in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use the mean of the three components instead of the function `rgb2gray` because it has some advantages in your case. (`rgb2gray` does something similar: it uses a weighted sum).

Subtracting the minimum and dividing by the maximum doesn't convert your image to binary. It will only scale all values to the range (0,1), which is the case in your example. This only means that all values are *between* 0 and 1, not exactly 0 or 1. If you want a binary image, i.e. only 0 and 1, you will need to use a threshold to convert the grayscale image to binary.

A method which is often used, is to calculate a threshold using Otsu's method:

```
threshold = graythresh(im);            % calculate threshold
binaryImage = im2bw(im,threshold);     % convert image to binary
```

If your image is saved as `uint8` then normalizing the image should convert your image to binary, as `uint8` only can handle integer numbers and any numbers between are rounded. That means you assume the optimal threshold to be at 0.5.

Comment: Daer Hbaderts.. Thanx for your post and suggestion. After this step I changed my image to binary and the resulted histogram of the binary image has only two values (0 and 1). I want to know the reason for these grey values in my histogram of the normalized image in the question. is my normalization technique wrong? if it is correct, why these values doesn't lie only in 0-1 range. why do I have these grey step values? Thank You

Comment: Your values **do** lie between 0 and 1.  "In 0-1 range" doesn't mean "only 0 and 1".

Comment: Exactly @nkjt . I added this to my answer.